# HERE Maps API event delays

Tags: javascript, leaflet, here-api

When panning a map with the HERE maps API, the 'mapviewchangeend' event is triggered a short time after the animation completes.  This means that is difficult to synchronise, say, a Leaflet overlay without the overlaid objects lagging behind.

```
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
                    defaultLayers.normal.map, ...    
var lMap = L.map('mapContainer', {zoomControl: false});
```

...

```
function onMapViewChange() {
   lMap.setView(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom(), {animation: false});
}

map.addEventListener('mapviewchange', function () {
   onMapViewChange();
});

map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', function () {
   onMapViewChange();
});
```

Is there a way to remove this delay?  I have experimented with different kinetic settings for H.mapevents.Behavior but so far without success.

Comment: See also http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can hook into the `sync` events being fired by the the [view model](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-viewmodel.html#h-map-viewmodel__sync-event) and the [viewport](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-viewport.html#h-map-viewport__sync-event). I seem to recall that these events fire synchronously when the map renders...

After some digging, I found the example showing something very similar on github:

[maps-api-for-javascript-examples/ground-overlay](https://github.com/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/blob/master/ground-overlay/js/app.js)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @echom.  It turns out that I was on the wrong track - Leaflet dragging needs to be disabled even if there is no base layer: `lMap.dragging.disable()`  My original code, as well as modified using the viewModel and ViewPort as you suggest now both remove the lag.